# Rails with remote Test Postgres DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-8.4

Studying at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ version 3.2

Stucked in the end of 6.2.1 section with the following:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
rake aborted!
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.108.1", user "sample_user", database "postgres", SSL on
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.108.1", user "sample_user", database "postgres", SSL off

Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge
```

192.168.108.1 is my ip. Why is it looking for it, if I have another entry in database.yml?
User sample_user is owner of all databases and has CREATEDB on them.
I can successfuly connect to any database on 192.168.108.2 with psql from 192.168.108.1

How cat I overcome it, still using remote postgres?

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :development do
gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
end
```

database.yml

```
common: &common
    adapter: postgresql
    username: sample_user
    password: qwerty123
    host: 192.168.108.2

development:
    <<: *common
    database: sample_db_dev

test:
    <<: *common
    database: sample_db_tst

production:
    <<: *common
    database: sample_db_pro
```

pg_hba.conf on 192.168.108.2

```
host    sample_db_dev   sample_user 192.168.108.1/32   md5
host    sample_db_tst   sample_user 192.168.108.1/32   md5
host    sample_db_pro   sample_user 192.168.108.1/32   md5
```

have no local pg_hba.conf on 192.168.108.1

ruby 1.9.3p125
Rails 3.2.3
psql (PostgreSQL) 8.4.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pg_hba.conf is a file on the PostgreSQL server to define which users are allowed to connect to which databases from which hosts using what authentication methods.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

So, that message is telling you that the server hasn't been told to allow the connection you are attempting. You must either make a connection which PostgreSQL has been told to allow, or tell it to allow this one by updating the pg_hba.conf file.

If you don't have access to server, and whoever does has not chosen to grant you PostgreSQL connection rights, you can't connect. That's the nature of security.

Comment: did you saw my local database.yml and my pg_hba.conf from DB server?

Comment: The lines you show from pg_hba.conf don't show any permissions for the postgres database mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know that there is system database "postgres". All works.

Comment: That was added just to provide a standard place to connect when you need to do "global" activities, like listing the databases. In PostgreSQL you need to connect to *some* database to be able to read shared tables (like `pg_database`). You can probably see the benefit of having a database which is always present even though it's not used to store anything.